# EJBProcessor exception handling

Tags: java, jboss, esb

I have a JBOSS ESB that uses a standard out of the box EJBProcessor action. How do I get hold of an exception, if the exception be thrown in the method call that was run in the EJB?

Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subclass `EJBProcessor` and override the process method like this:

```
@Override
public Message process(Message pMessage) {
  try {
    pMessage = super.process(pMessage);
  } catch (Throwable wEx) {
    handleProcessError(pMessage, wEx);
  }
  return pMessage;
}
```

You will more than likely catch an instance of `ActionProcessingException`, and you can look at the cause to see the exception in your `EJB`.

Your action configuration in your `jboss-esb.xml` will remain exactly the same, except you will substitute the name of your subclass for `org.jboss.soa.esb.actions.EJBProcessor`.